# Width and height of tagged segments of photos in facebook-graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to extract the tagged segments of my friend's facebook photos to train a facial recognition algorithm. Although https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/ describes the x and y position of the tag in a photo, I don't know how to retrieve the width and height of the rectangle that appears when you hover over a face in a facebook photo. Is it possible to find out the width and height of the tagged face in the photo?

Comment: There is no width and and height. To my understanding, the x and y are the center.

Comment: @TommyCrush There seems to be an end to the tagged rectangular area. I would like the width and height of this area.

Comment: Right, but it does not seem to be available via the api.

Comment: @TommyCrush OK well this is a possible answer to my question. Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, grabbing the height and width of a tag box is not possible via the Facebook API.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same situation. What I did was whip up a quick script in python and opencv2 for detecting faces using HAAR Cascades. This gives us rectangles aroud the detected faces. Since the x and y parameters of the tag represent the center of the tag, we look for the face-rectangle which surrounds the tag position. If multiple such rectangles are overlapping we could chose the one whose center is the closest to the tag position.